# Use TYPO3 only for Backend

Tags: typo3

I am new to TYPO3. A customer wants TYPO3. It's a quite large project with WIKI, JOBS, NEWS, PROJECTS, etc.

As far as I can see, there are several ways I could go.
What would you as an experienced TYPO3 developer suggest as the easeast, fastest, most efficient approach to reach our goal?

**A: Leave the object graph in TYPO3**
**A1:** I've seen with the DOMAIN_MODEL classes there is some kind of rudimentary ORM integrated. This approach means, we would need to reevent the wheel with WIKI, NEWS, etc.

**A2:** It would be great to use existing extentions for WIKI, NEWS,... The customer wants them to be related (add a wiki entry to news or new to projects). That means the existing extentions have to be extented

**B:** Use TYPO3 only for normal content like pages (legal, contact, landig pages...) and as a backend for dynamic content as well, which is stored and handled in an external API. This approach also means, we would need to reevent the wheel with WIKI, NEWS, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use TYPO3 for content and news (use news extension for that) and look for a suitable standalone wiki solution. Then connect both systems the way you need them to interact. No wheels have to be reinvented.